# How to cite websites in IEEE format using IEEETranN?

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I am trying to include the following reference in my references list.

```
@misc{CognitiveAccessibilityatW3C2022,
title = {{Cognitive Accessibility at W3C}},
url = {https://www.w3.org/WAI/cognitive/},
urldate = {2022-09-15}
}
```

I am using a patched version of [IEEETranN.bst](https://gist.github.com/ezod/3373556). And I would like the reference to look as follows (following the [IEEE reference guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf)):

```
[1] “Cognitive accessibility at w3c.” https://www.w3.org/WAI/cognitive/ (accessed Sep. 15, 2022).
```

Leaving the code as is, this is how the reference looks:

```
[1] “Cognitive Accessibility at W3C.” [Online]. Available: https://www.w3.org/WAI/cognitive/
```

How can I alter the code to ensure that the reference is in the format `[1] “Cognitive accessibility at w3c.” https://www.w3.org/WAI/cognitive/ (accessed Sep. 15, 2022).` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! One easy workaround is to put everything in the `note` field.

Comment: Yes I found this as a backup, but I would prefer to do it the right way, if there is one

Answer (score 1):

I think `accessed Sep. 15, 2022` is not necessary. You can use `@electronic` directly. If there is any problem, the editor will modify it for you.

```
@electronic{CognitiveAccessibilityatW3C2022,
author = {{W3C}},
title  = {{Cognitive Accessibility at W3C}},
url    = {https://www.w3.org/WAI/cognitive/},
month  = sep,
year   = {2022},
note   = {accessed Sep. 15, 2022}
}
```

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\cite{CognitiveAccessibilityatW3C2022}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]